# how to run program parallel to opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, parallel-processing, glut

i want to run opengl and i also want that my c code is executed... xD
After the window is created no code is executed... is this normal ?
or do i need just to understand opengl a bit better :D

Maybe i need to put my c code in some opengl loop xD like into the idle function^^

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : cpu_Emulation_19-10-13.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================
//https://fms.komkon.org/EMUL8/HOWTO.html

// todo: iam programming the dissambler which just checks my given in commands.. 1927 - 31.10.2019
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "C8Klasse.h"
#include "Cartridge.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <intrin.h> // damit kann man zyklen auslesen...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c
using namespace std;
//  Windows
//#ifdef _WIN32

// what does this whole thing: it ist a Chip8 Interpreter
unsigned short int memory[1000]; // annahem
void initMemory() {
    memory[0] = 0;
    memory[1] = 1;
}
void display() {

}
void glutInitRoutines() {
    glutInitWindowSize(64, 32);
    glutCreateWindow("Chip8 V5");
    glutDisplayFunc(display); // die obige Funktion display wird als Bildchirm behandler bekanntgemacht
    //glutSpecialFunc( process_Normal_Keys);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 32.0, 64.0, 0.0);
    //glutIdleFunc( idle);
    glutMainLoop();
    //void glutIdleFunc(void (*func)(void)
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //screen
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitRoutines(); // initialisation for opengGL window
    //screen end
    char rom_name[] = "img Fishie.ch8";

    // #Start Chip8
    C8Klasse c8; // lege interpreter an
    c8.initSpeicher(); // initialisiere den Speicher zu 0
    // #Setup cartridge
    Cartridge testCartridge; // declare a Cartridge ( its the rom with the game data !!
    testCartridge.readInOpcodeFromFileInArray(rom_name); // reads opcode of a data-file (should be in workspace) into an intern array
    testCartridge.printOpcode();
    // # Cartridgecode to Chip8 Memory
    c8.setOpCode(testCartridge);// here the Opcode of the game is passed to the c8 CPU ( Cartridge ->internal memory )!
    c8.printMemory(); // here the c8 internal memory is printed out, should be same form 0x200 to 0xfff with cartridge , since the game has been read in !
    c8.printMemory(0x200); // prints memory by starting at given paramater address !

    cout << "\n please press enter to continue with the program !" << endl;
    cin.get();
    cout << "enter" << endl;
    unsigned short int counter = 0x00; // ein zykluscounter - zählt zeit bis zum nächsten unsigned short interrupt....
    unsigned short int opCode = 0;
    //##########################################################   main loop
    c8.setPC(0x200); // starte mit dem PC auf Adresse 0x200 !
    for (int i = 0; i < testCartridge.getOpcodeLength(); i++) {
        // opCOde is a unsigned short int ( 16 Bit ) the memory is just 8 Bit ! so please make some bit-amipulation: executableOpcode=(opcode1 <<8) | (opcode2)
        opCode = ((unsigned short int) ((c8.getMemAtPC() & (0xff))) << 8);
        c8.incrementPCCounter(1); // increment PC
        opCode = opCode | (((unsigned short int) (c8.getMemAtPC() & (0xff))));
        c8.incrementPCCounter(1); // increment PC -- for the next round
        c8.dissembler(opCode); // so if the opcode variable is fille with 2 Bytes please run the dissembler !
        cout << "\ncurrent pc: 0x" << hex << c8.getPC();
        //      cout << ", the read out OpCode is:0x" << hex << opCode; // show opcode.
        printf(" the read OpCode is: 0x%04x", opCode);
        cin.get();
        // man muss bei den Befehlen unterscheiden:  befehle fangen mit einer fixen Zahl an und haben dann variablen!
        // man muss deswegen zuerst schauen welche zahl am Anfang steht oder , man muss nach einer Zahlenkombinatuon suchen
        //Befehle: http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/chip8/C8TECH10.HTM
        //Hex to ASCII converter : https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
 *
 All instructions are 2 bytes long and are stored most-significant-byte first.
 In memory, the first byte of each instruction should be located at an even addresses.
 3.1 - Standard Chip-8 Instructions
 00E0 - CLS
 00EE - RET
 0nnn - SYS addr
 1nnn - JP addr
 2nnn - CALL addr
 3xkk - SE Vx, byte
 4xkk - SNE Vx, byte
 5xy0 - SE Vx, Vy
 6xkk - LD Vx, byte
 7xkk - ADD Vx, byte
 8xy0 - LD Vx, Vy
 8xy1 - OR Vx, Vy
 8xy2 - AND Vx, Vy
 8xy3 - XOR Vx, Vy
 8xy4 - ADD Vx, Vy
 8xy5 - SUB Vx, Vy
 8xy6 - SHR Vx {, Vy}
 8xy7 - SUBN Vx, Vy
 8xyE - SHL Vx {, Vy}
 9xy0 - SNE Vx, Vy
 Annn - LD I, addr
 Bnnn - JP V0, addr
 Cxkk - RND Vx, byte
 Dxyn - DRW Vx, Vy, nibble
 Ex9E - SKP Vx
 ExA1 - SKNP Vx
 Fx07 - LD Vx, DT
 Fx0A - LD Vx, K
 Fx15 - LD DT, Vx
 Fx18 - LD ST, Vx
 Fx1E - ADD I, Vx
 Fx29 - LD F, Vx
 Fx33 - LD B, Vx
 Fx55 - LD [I], Vx
 Fx65 - LD Vx, [I]
 3.2 - Super Chip-48 Instructions
 00Cn - SCD nibble
 00FB - SCR
 00FC - SCL
 00FD - EXIT
 00FE - LOW
 00FF - HIGH
 Dxy0 - DRW Vx, Vy, 0
 Fx30 - LD HF, Vx
 Fx75 - LD R, Vx
 Fx85 - LD Vx, R
 * */
```

Comment: i another program e.g. i calculated my alien-sprite after a key detection...i think through idle() display is called everytime nothing else is called ... but for this code it would change the structure .. it wouldnt be that bad ... but i cant imagine that opengl is that unflexible.. but ok there are improvements i guess. maybe sdl is smarter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call glutMainLoop(), your program will enter a loop that looks a bit like:

```cpp
void glutMainLoop()
{
  while(true)
  {
    MSG msg = getWindowEvent();
    switch(msg)
    {
    case QUIT: exit(0); break; //< NOTE: method never returns!!
    /* snip */
    }
  }
}
```

Which is the reason you cannot run any code after glutMainLoop() has been called. If you just want to run the code at the bottom of main once (at the point of app startup), then simply move glutMainLoop() from your routine setup func, to be the very last call in main(). If you want to run that code *at the same time* as updating the GL window, you have a couple of options:

1. Just run the std::cin code whenever you want (as a response to a keypress, etc). It will cause the OpenGL window to freeze whilst that code is run, simply because it's a single threaded application, so the redraw can't happen until you've finished.
2. Use the glut keypress/keyrelease callbacks to fill a global std::string with the entered text (one key press at a time). When you detect enter, parse and process your op codes form the global string. Do not call cin, and render the text on screen via OpenGL (or, if you are extremely lazy, call glutSetWindowTitle, which avoids the need to find code to render a font on screen - although glut can help out there!)
3. Create a second thread for the std::cin based code (if that's something you really want to do?). You then have to deal with the bother of threading, which is probably overkill in this case imho.

Personally, I'd go for option 2.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest ditching glut entirely and going with a real framework like GLFW.

Comment: thank you ! wow ... yes i think this were good answers like 3Dave said ! .... i think i need such a "real" framework .. because it will be maybe easier in the beginning for me. the 3 options you mentioned are to complicated for me. ... ok but the disadvantage would be, that i have to understand "frameworks" xD i dont know about it... oh .. maybe i really a have to look for one of your 3 solutions xD

Comment: Ah .. maybe for you it is easy and you maybe told me it implicit etc. but void glutPostRedisplay (void); is a really interesting part of openGL for me i think. i could run everytime a code ... yes it is the main loop you mentioned... a yeah but then you are right it is no more parellel.. ok but for my case it will  maybe enough   ..void idle(){
 cout<<"lol"<<endl;
}